# Maximal ideal in valuation ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In the lectures I've attended on algebraic number theory, there is a standard definition of a valuation ring,
$$\mathcal{O} = \{x \in K: v(x) \geq 0\}$$
$$\mathcal{P} = \{x \in K: v(x) > 0\},$$
where $K$ is a field and $v$ an exponential valuation. $\mathcal{P}$ is then easily proven to be a unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. However, a more general setting is introduced right after that: let $\mathcal{O}$ be an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions. Then $\mathcal{O}$ is called a valuation ring, if
$$\forall x \in K^*: (x \in \mathcal{O}) \lor (x^{-1} \in \mathcal{O}),$$
and then
$$\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathcal{O}:x^{-1} \notin \mathcal{O}\}$$
is claimed to be its unique maximal ideal. I have two questions:

1. First of all, how does one prove that $\mathcal{P}$ in the second case is indeed an ideal, and also maximal and unique?
2. Second, are the two definitions equivalent? Meaning if we define an arbitrary $v$ on $K$ in the second scenario, will then $\mathcal{O}$ be the same as in the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1., note that every $x\in R$ not in $\mathcal{P}$ is invertible in $R$, so once one has that $\mathcal{P}$ is an ideal it is automatically the unique maximal ideal. Now if $x,y\in\mathcal{P}$ then since either $\frac{x}{y}\in\mathcal{O}$ or $\frac{y}{x}\in\mathcal{O}$, you get  $\frac{x+y}{x}\in\mathcal{O}$ or $\frac{x+y}{y}\in\mathcal{O}$. So if $x+y\notin\mathcal{P}$ it would follow that $\frac{1}{x}\in\mathcal{O}$ or $\frac{1}{y}\in\mathcal{O}$, a contradiction.

For 2. the answer depends a bit on the generality of the definition of an exponential valuation in your course. If an exponential valuation is a homomorphism $v:K^\times\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $v(x+y)\geq\min\{v(x),v(y)\}$, then the answer is NO. Valuation rings in the general sense correspond to valuations $v:K^\times\rightarrow\Gamma$ for arbitrary ordered abelian groups $\Gamma$. For more on this see e.g. Chapters 1 and 2 of the book Valued Fields by Engler-Prestel.